# How do you perturb a polygon so no two of its edges lie on the same line?

Tags: java, polygon, computational-geometry, floating-point-precision

You are given a simple polygon defined by points in R<sup>2</sup>. You can move a point by x and y axes by some small ε (e.g. 1e-4). What is the algorithm to move the points to make sure that no two edges of the polygon lie exactly on the same line?

"Being on the same line" is usually defined as having a small enough difference between angles of two lines, but for the purpose of this particular problem I only consider segments being on the same line if they have exactly 0 difference in their angles or line equations or however you define them.

**EDIT:**

Here's some code. It solves the problem only for axis-parallel edges.

```
package org.tendiwa.geometry;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;
import org.jgrapht.UndirectedGraph;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Set;

public final class SameLineGraphEdgesPerturbations {
    private static Comparator<Segment2D> HORIZONTAL_COMPARATOR = (a, b) -> {
        assert a.start.y == a.end.y && b.start.y == b.end.y;
        double d = a.start.y - b.start.y;
        if (d < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (d > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };
    private static Comparator<Segment2D> VERTICAL_COMPARATOR = (a, b) -> {
        assert a.start.x == a.end.x && b.start.x == b.end.x;
        double d = a.start.x - b.start.x;
        if (d < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (d > 0) {
            return 1;
        }
        return 0;
    };

    /**
     * Checks if some of graph's edges are segments of the same line, and perturbs vertices and edges of this graph
     * so it contains no such segments.
     * <p>
     * This class is designed to work with graphs that represent simple polygons. You can use it with other classes
     * of graphs, but that probably won't be useful.
     * 
     *
     * @param graph
     *  A planar graph to be mutated.
     */
    public static void perturbIfHasSameLineEdges(UndirectedGraph<Point2D, Segment2D> graph, double magnitude) {
        ArrayList<Segment2D> verticalEdges = new ArrayList<>(graph.edgeSet().size());
        ArrayList<Segment2D> horizontalEdges = new ArrayList<>(graph.edgeSet().size());
        for (Segment2D edge : graph.edgeSet()) {
            if (edge.start.x == edge.end.x) {
                verticalEdges.add(edge);
            } else if (edge.start.y == edge.end.y) {
                horizontalEdges.add(edge);
            }
        }
        verticalEdges.sort(VERTICAL_COMPARATOR);
        horizontalEdges.sort(HORIZONTAL_COMPARATOR);
        /*
         The algorithm is the following:
         For each axis-parallel edge in a list of edges sorted by static coordinate,
         perturb its start if the next edge in list has the same static coordinate (i.e., lies on the same line).
         That way if we have N same line axis-parallel edges (placed consecutively in an array because it is sorted),
         N-1 of those will be perturbed, except for the last one (because there is no next edge for the last one).
         Perturbing the last one is not necessary because bu perturbing other ones the last one becomes non-parallel
         to each of them.
          */
        int size = verticalEdges.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Point2D vertex = verticalEdges.get(i).start; // .end would be fine too
            if (vertex.x == verticalEdges.get(i + 1).start.x) {
                perturbVertexAndItsEdges(vertex, graph, magnitude);
            }
        }
        size = horizontalEdges.size() - 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            Point2D vertex = horizontalEdges.get(i).start; // .end would be fine too
            if (vertex.y == horizontalEdges.get(i + 1).start.y) {
                if (!graph.containsVertex(vertex)) {
                    // Same edge could already be perturbed in a loop over vertical edges.
                    continue;
                }
                perturbVertexAndItsEdges(vertex, graph, magnitude);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void perturbVertexAndItsEdges(
        Point2D vertex,
        UndirectedGraph<Point2D, Segment2D> graph,
        double magnitude
    ) {
        Set<Segment2D> edges = ImmutableSet.copyOf(graph.edgesOf(vertex));
        assert edges.size() == 2 : edges.size();
        // We move by both axes so both vertical and
        // horizontal edges will become not on the same line
        // with those with which they were on the same line.
        Point2D newVertex = vertex.moveBy(magnitude, magnitude);
        graph.addVertex(newVertex);
        for (Segment2D edge : edges) {
            boolean removed = graph.removeEdge(edge);
            assert removed;
            // It should be .end, not .start, because in perturbIfHasSameLineEdges we used
            // vertex = edges.get(i).start
            if (edge.start == vertex) {
                graph.addEdge(newVertex, edge.end);
            } else {
                assert edge.end == vertex;
                graph.addEdge(newVertex, edge.start);
            }
        }
        assert graph.degreeOf(vertex) == 0 : graph.degreeOf(vertex);
        graph.removeVertex(vertex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

Comment: @KenWhite This is not a homework.

Comment: You've copied/pasted what appears to be an assignment, asked for an answer, and provided nothing to show you've made any effort to solve the problem. It certainly *reads* like a homework assignment, and your stating it isn't doesn't change that appearance. You've even stated it from the point of an assignment: "You are given" and "for the purpose of this particular problem I", which certainly sounds like an instructor wrote it.

Comment: @KenWhite Will the code change it? Should I post a link to my actively updated github repository with that code?

Comment: @KenWhite If this is enough to prove I have "minimal understanding of the problem etc" I'd be grateful if you removed your unnecessary close  vote.

Comment: Sorry to ask that instead of answering, but what is your purpose ? If what you want is to make sure that you can find the intersection point of any two edges and avoid degeneracies, you may be worsening the problem by introducing perturbations because computing intersections is unstable. Can we have more context ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust The purpose is that I want to apply a skeletonization algorithm to a polygon: https://code.google.com/p/campskeleton/ Unfortunately, that algorithm may sometimes fail to finish successfuly because of two edges being parallel. I don't see a way to determine ahead of time which would be the problem edges, so the simplest thing I could come up with is having all the polygon vertices to be slightly perturbed, so its skeleton won't change much in its shape, but there aren't any degeneracies.

Comment: Strange, the algorithm is deemed robust. How can it degenerate with parallel sides, in such a case there should beat least two other sides to form a quadrilateral. You should pinpoint the exact place in the algorithm where it goes wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust The author of the algorithm describes that case as an open problem: http://twak.blogspot.ru/2011/01/degeneracy-in-weighted-straight.html See figures 21, 25, 26, 27.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

For every edge, compute some scalar direction parameter (such as the angle, and as you suggest can be other, but needs to be scalar). This will take time O(N).

Sort all parameters so obtained, in time O(N Lg(N)).

Find the repeated values in the list in O(N).

For every group of equal values, introduce the perturbations in a way to be sure that you don't create new coincidences (find the closest neighboring values and perturb every equal values with a different multiple of a fraction of the gap size; for example, 0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4 has a repetition of 0.2, and the closest gap is 0.1; so you could perturb as 0.1, 0.2-0.001, 0.2, 0.2+0.001, 0.4). Or just perturb randomly.

Now comes a non-bulletproof step: build the perturbed support lines and intersect them so that you find the positions of the perturbed vertexes.

This is not bulletproof because you could accidentally create new collinear edges this way, and it is better to restart the whole procedure to check. If you don't get a solution after two iterations, you might be in trouble...

Comment: This is exactly what I've come up since I posted the question. Yes, this is not bullet-proof at all. After thinking for some time, I fugured that it would be much simpler and efficient to just randomly shift vertices within ±ε, and then checking what you've got and then randomly shifting again those edges that still appear to be collinear. And then throw an exception if this sequence of actions doesn't get rid of all the collinear edges in `N` iterations. I guess, chances to get an exception would be astronimically low. Or am I wrong?